# How do you filter nested loops using Java 8 streams and filters?

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-8, java-stream

How do you filter nested loops using java8 streams and filters?

Suppose I have a list of cars (`List<Car>`), each car having a list of Engines (`List<Engine>`), each engine having a `List<Parts>`.
In regular Java this structure can be described as:

```
for(Car car : cars) {
    for (Engine engine : car.getEngines()) {
        for (Part part : engine.getParts()) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose I initialise the list of cars as:

```
List<Car> cars =  new ArrayList<Car>(Arrays.asList(new Car(), new Car(), new Car()));
cars.get(0).setEngines(null);
cars.get(1).setEngines(new ArrayList<Engine>());
cars.get(2).setEngines(new ArrayList<Engine>() {{
    add(new Engine());
    add(null);
    add(new Engine());  
}});
```

If I want to filter out nulls of `List<Engine>`, then I would do

```
cars.stream().filter(p -> p.getEngines() != null).forEach(System.out::println);
```

If I want to filter out empty arraylists of List, then I would do

```
cars.stream().filter(p -> !p.getEngines().isEmpty()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

But how do I remove the null `Engine` in a 3rd car and yet keep two other engines attached to the original list structure? In other words, can we go into the 2nd, 3rd, nth level of hierarchy with Java 8 filters or do filters only work on the top-most layer? I also tried to use `.anyMatch()`, without much luck.

just to further clarify, consider the following example:
I have 3 cars in my garage.  Each car has 3 placeholders for engine.  Each engine has 3 placeholders for parts that make up the engine:

```
Car #1: 
 Engine#1: part1, part2, part3
 Engine#2: null, part2, empty
 Engine#3: part1, null, part3
Car #2: 
 Engine#1: part1, part2, part3
 empty:    null, null, null
 null:     null, null, null
Car #3: 
 Engine#1: null, empty, part3
 Engine#2: null, part2, empty
 Engine#3: part1, null, part3
```

Question: how do we use Java 8 .filter, such that when after filtering I get the following:

```
Car #1: 
 Engine#1: part1, part2, part3
 Engine#2: part2, 
 Engine#3: part1, part3
Car #2: 
 Engine#1: part1, part2, part3
Car #1: 
 Engine#1: part3
 Engine#2: part2,
 Engine#3: part1,part3
```

=======================

## Another example

Guys I hope this example that I just made up is clearer:.. Essentially it is the same as above only it is more verbose and instead of cars we can think of banks to minimize abstraction.   For conciseness I make all fields public, I hope you don't mind.

Suppose I am affiliated with 4 banks in my 'bank wallet'
Bank#1: 
  I physically bank here.  I am forced to have 3 accounts, but only are 2 filled with some cash and 3rd is yet to opened (ie null)
Bank #2:
  I plan to bank here. Account support structure is created (empty ArrayList), but no accounts are added
Bank #3:
 I filled out some marketing form.  They have me in their CRM but no accounts will ever be opened
Bank #4:
 This bank burned down, there is an artifact placeholder in the wallet, which is null.

The following code describes this:

```
public class Bank_Wallet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Bank> banks = new ArrayList<Bank>(Arrays.asList(new Bank(), new Bank(), new Bank(), null));
        // 1st bank with physical accounts, but one of them is null
        banks.get(0).accounts = Arrays.asList(new Account(), null, new Account());
        // 2nd bank with empty accounts  
        banks.get(1).accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();

        System.out.println("RAW original");
        banks.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("\nFiltered result...   ");
        banks.stream()// get stream
                .filter(p -> p != null) // get rid of null banks
                .filter(p -> p.accounts != null) // get rid of null accounts
                .filter(p -> !p.accounts.isEmpty()) // get rid of empty accounts
                // .filter(p->p.accounts. ?????? ??) ?? how do I remove null account from the remaining bank entry?
                .forEach(System.out::println);

    }// main
}
```

The support classes are here:

```
public class Bank {
    public String name;
    public static int counter = 0;
    public List<Account> accounts;

    public Bank() {
        this.name = "Bank: #" + Bank.counter++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bank [name=" + this.name + ", accounts=" + this.accounts + "]";
    }

public class Account {
    public String name;
    public static int counter;

    public Account() {
        this.name = "Account: " + Account.counter++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account [name=" + this.name + "]";
    }

}
```

when you run this code you will see that after suggested filtering all I am left with is

```
Bank [name=Bank: #0, accounts=[Account [name=Account: 0], null, Account [name=Account: 1]]]
```

Question:
What other filter do I need do add to the code to get the above result not show null in the accounts and yet retain the overall structure (Bank->Account->etc->etc)

```
Bank [name=Bank: #0, accounts=[Account [name=Account: 0], Account [name=Account: 1]]]
```

Comment: run map over each entry in the outer list.  The map function should filter out what you don't want.

Comment: Could you be more specific in what you're trying to achieve with your loops ? I think Andreas raised a good point showing me that I made too many assumptions about what you are looking for, because your question is not specific enough. Just give us a sample input along with the desired output

Comment: So you want to print the whole car, excluding any null/empty components?

Comment: Is that something to be displayed or something to be collected ?

Comment: yes the entire car structure (list) with nulls/empties filtered out at different depth levels using java 8 filter

Comment: If you're relying on `Car.toString()`, there's nothing you can do with streams or even loops to filter out sub-components. You have to either implement `toString()` differently, or print out components iteratively.

Comment: @Dici, it can be collected as well as displayed.  Collected is much preferred.

Comment: @shmosel, yes that is what I currently have:  I have 3 for-loops and get it filtered out that way, but though java 8 filter might've been a better solution

Comment: @JavaFan collecting this would involve either mutating the cars or creating new ones, which one is expected ?

Comment: Did you know that you can simply use the result of `Arrays.asList` everywhere, where a `List` is required, i.e. that you don’t have to clutter your code with gazillion different attempts of creating and filling `ArrayList`s?

Comment: The “clarification” is rather confusing. What does it mean when a “part” is labeled “empty” and how can “empty” or even `null` lists contains three `null` elements?

Comment: guys, give me couple hours  - I will come up with another example with more detailed statement of the problem.  Sorry for all the confusion...

Comment: @JavaFan Did you even solve this problem?

Answer (score 8):

The stream equivalent of

```
for(Car car : cars) {
    for (Engine engine : car.getEngines()) {
        for (Part part : engine.getParts()) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

is

```
cars.stream()
    .flatMap(car -> car.getEngines().stream())
    .flatMap(engine -> engine.getParts().stream())
    .forEach(part -> { /* ... */ });
```

The `...` code will however not have access to `car` and `engine`.

To check for null, you can check in two places:

```
cars.stream()
    .flatMap(car -> car.getEngines().stream())
    .filter(engine -> engine != null)
    .flatMap(engine -> engine.getParts().stream())
    .forEach(part -> { /* ... */ });
```

or

```
cars.stream()
    .flatMap(car -> car.getEngines()
                       .stream()
                       .filter(engine -> engine != null))
    .flatMap(engine -> engine.getParts().stream())
    .forEach(part -> { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: He wants to display the cars, not the parts (from my understanding). That's why `flatMap` cannot be used here, or not this way. We don't want to lose the reference to the car. Also, all your snippets may throw a `NullPointerException`

Comment: this is really good but as @Dici pointed out, i want to display the cars not the parts themselves.

Comment: @JavaFan How does the text *"But how do I remove the null Engine in a 3rd car and yet keep two other engines attached to the original list structure?"* jive with only wanting the car? If you only want to car, what is the entire point of filtering the engine list? And what does any of that have to do with the part list? Of course, the concept of a car having more than one engine is unusual to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

And why do you not simply write this ?

```
cars.stream()
    .filter(car -> notEmpty(car.getEngines()))
    .filter(car -> car.getEngines().stream().allMatch(engine -> notEmpty(engine.getParts())))
    .forEach(System.out::println);

public static <T> boolean notEmpty(Collection<T> collection) {
   return collection != null && !collection.isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: `getEngines()` returns `List<Engine>` (or similar), which doesn't have `getParts`.

Comment: The `System.out::println` will be called once for each `Car`, which is *very* different result than the `for` loop code, which will execute `...` for each `Part`.

Comment: @Andreas I think we understood the question differently. To be fair, it's not very well explained what we should answer to. I took the first snippet as pseudo-code to illustrate the `"levels"`, not as actual code. If it is actual code then you're absolutely right, but it would sound odd to print the cars several times

Comment: just one second guys I will provide an example in the original post what I want.  Apologies for not being clear

Answer (score 2):

How about following?

```
    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>(Arrays.asList(new Car("C0"), new Car("C1"), new Car("C2")));
    cars.get(0).setEngines(new ArrayList<Engine>());
    cars.get(1).setEngines(new ArrayList<Engine>());
    cars.get(2).setEngines(Arrays.asList(new Engine("C2E1"), new Engine("C2E2"), null));

    cars.stream().filter(c -> Objects.nonNull(c.getEngines())).forEach(c -> {
        System.out.printf("Car %s ", c);
        c.getEngines().stream().filter(e -> Objects.nonNull(e) && Objects.nonNull(e.getParts())).forEach(e -> {
            System.out.printf(" Engine %s ", e);
            e.getParts().stream().filter(p -> Objects.nonNull(p))
                    .forEach(p -> System.out.printf("Part %s", p));
        });
        System.out.println();
    });
```

Produces following :

Car C0

Car C1

Car C2 Engine C2E1 Part DefaultPart Engine C2E2 Part DefaultPart

Have overriden "toString" for Car/Engine/Part classes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `removeIf()` like following:

```
 cars.removeIf(car -> car.getEngines() == null);

 cars.forEach(c->System.out.println("Car :"+c);
```